# Understanding Ruby's load paths

Tags: ruby

I'm a little confused about why my project can't load the files it needs, it's a really simple project tree:

```
processor/
  bin/
  lib/
    processor.rb
    processor/
      mapper.rb
      reducer.rb
```

and my `processor.rb` file looks like

```
require 'processor/mapper'
require 'processor/reducer'

class Processor

end
```

And just for testing it that file mapper looks like:

```
class Mapper
  def run
    puts "running map"
  end
end
```

But running `ruby lib/processor.rb` results in:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- processor/mapper (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from lib/processor.rb:3:in `<class:Processor>'
    from lib/processor.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: "Ruby's" has an apostrophe because you're indicating the load paths belong to it, rather than that there's multiple rubies.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH` will not include your `lib` directory by default (even though that's where the file you're running is located).

You can either tell the `ruby` interpreter to include it:

```
ruby -Ilib lib/processor.rb
```

Or you can add the `lib` folder to the load path:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require  'processor/mapper'
...
```

Answer (score 37):

Ruby 1.9 no longer includes "." in the load path.  Do `require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/processor/mapper"` or use `require_relative`.

You can always determine the current load path by inspecting `$LOAD_PATH` (or `$:`)

(edited: $LOAD_PATH not $:LOAD_PATH)

Comment: His exact scenario actually wouldn't work in 1.8 either (running `ruby lib/processor.rb` from the root `processor` folder). However, running `ruby processor.rb` while in the `lib` folder would work on 1.8, but not on 1.9.

Answer (score 7):

Use Ruby's `require_relative` in this case:

```
require_relative "processor/mapper"
```