# Ruby, load classes and methods from different script

Tags: ruby

So I'm still a bit confused at how load paths work basically I have a file structure like:

```
my_app
  bin
    my_bin
  lib
    processor.rb
```

So the problem is the the file `my_bin` is a bin file (in ruby) that is supposed to call a class and method in `processor.rb`

The bin file requires gems and other stuff at the top, but how can I have the classes in  `processor.rb` loaded?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try the answers to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671318/understanding-rubys-load-paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 1.9.2 you can do:

```
require_relative '../lib/processor'
```

in 1.8.7 you can do:

```
$: << "/absolute/path/to_parent_of_lib/lib"

require 'processor'
```