# Fixing "custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load" errors

Tags: ruby

I understand that after Ruby 1.9.2, '.' is no longer in your path for security reasons. This seems to be a problem when using certain gems (ones not updated to 1.9 I imagine?), a problem that throws errors like

`$HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': cannot load such file -- rubylog (LoadError)`

I've seen and fixed this problem once, by (perhaps naively) changing some requires into require_relatives: https://github.com/mathpunk/MongoDB_Koans/commit/e2f7898347d328450ec121d22f701508f389cc53

Now I'd like to use rubylog, and I'm getting the custom_require error, so I tried the same trick:
https://github.com/mathpunk/rubylog/commit/995e13dccc6a197d280d0783f3fb7fe50deabd02

but this time, I'm just getting the same error. What else can I try?

**ETA:** All this time, I've been using `sudo gem install blah` to install gems, and for some reason, for rubylog it's `gem install rubylog` that does it. (Something to do with RVM?) So now everything works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the library directory to your LOAD_PATH:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

See [Understanding Ruby's load paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671318/understanding-rubys-load-paths)\

Edit: I assumed you had a `rubylog` directory wherever your script was running from. If your script can't find `rubylog` then you need to add that location to your load path:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift('/path/to/rubylog')
```

Are you sure you have the rubylog libraries? `gem install rubylog`

Comment: I must not understand your/your link's solution. Adding the following to the file I'm running does not change anything: `$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'rubylog'`

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails at `require 'rubylog'` - so it can't find rubylog.rb itself. So just add dir containing rubylog.rb to load path - something like `$: << 'rubylog'` might help.