# How can I execute a Ruby script as executable file?

Tags: ruby, compilation, executable

i want to execute my ruby script as executable file and also i should execute at /usr/bin/ directory. I know it is possible like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts "hello"
```

And

```
chmod +x hello
```

But I also want to require some ruby file.

For example if I add

```
require './other_ruby_script'
```

into my codes and I move the Ruby executable file to /usr/bin/, it gives me error for:

cannot load such file 'other_ruby_script'

I want to execute the Ruby file at /usr/bin directory.

So maybe I should compile it? But I couldn't compile because i didn't understand when google searches "How to compile?".

How can i create executable ruby code as suitable format for my codes. (require './other_file'). And i don't have to execute like this ./hello my executable file. Just i should execute as hello

Comment: `other_file` should be in the library path then. One option is to package it as a gem.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative 'other_ruby_script'
puts "hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you ask how to [configure the right loadpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671318/understanding-rubys-load-paths). First, in your script I would do a:

```
puts $:
```

This should print whether you are loading the right Ruby environment (might be a problem if you are using rbenv or rvm). For example I get:

```
/Users/pmu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/Users/pmu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0
/Users/pmu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby
```

As long as your loadpath does not contain the directory with the script 'other_ruby_script' you will get this error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- other_ruby_script
```

So, you should try to add the load path with:

```
$:.unshift "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../some_path"
```

If you are not loading the Ruby environment in the first place, your line:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

needs to be setup to load the environment from Rbenv or Rvm

Comment: May be If i compile my ruby script, is it more easy? Because i work on  a ruby project. It has many other ruby file.

Comment: Google does not give a result on the subject, because Ruby works with a Virtual Machine that compile code dynamically, like Java, Python or Perl. There are no compilers as far as I know. You need to learn how to load dependencies dynamically when working with Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a shell script from where you execute the ruby file.
You will need to export PATH and GEM_HOME in the shell script. The shell script will be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
export GEM_HOME = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
cd /path/to/ruby_script
ruby file_name.rb
```

You will get PATH and GEM_HOME by the following commands:

```
echo $PATH
echo $GEM_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is for a linux environment but this answer may help a Windows user who stumbles upon this in the future.

There are some packaging Gems for Ruby available [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/packaging_to_executables).

The most popular one is [OCRA](https://github.com/larsch/ocra) (One Click Ruby Application), which is available as both a Gem and a standalone Ruby file, and will package your Ruby project into a Windows executable.