# rspec 3.0.1 not working in test case

Tags: rspec

I have a ~/Projects folder with the following files inside:

bowling.rb & bowling_spec.rb

Both files are the same as those described in rspec's index page (http://rspec.info/) in order to test the gem.

When I try to execute bowling_spec.rb I get the following message:

```
ak@ak-ku:~/Projects$ rspec bowling_spec.rb 
/home/ak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bowling (LoadError)
    from /home/ak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/ak/Projects/bowling_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `load'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `each'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/ak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

What can I do about this? Why is this not working?

I'm using ruby 2.0.0p481 under rvm 1.25.27 in Kubuntu. Rails is 4.1.1 and I installed everything today.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Ruby's load paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671318/understanding-rubys-load-paths)

Comment: Although the error is somewhat different the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671318/understanding-rubys-load-paths Also, RSpec 3.0.1 is documented here https://relishapp.com/rspec. rspec.info is for RSpec 1.