# Rails whenever not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, whenever

I would like to have a task that simply substracts a certain value from my user model at every 5 minutes.
My code:

schedule.rb

```
every 5.minutes do
 runner 'Site::SubstractSomething.execute'
end
```

app/jobs/SubstractSomething.rb

```
module Site
 class SubstractSomething
  def initialize
  end

  def execute
   @users = ::User.all
   @users.each { |user| user.update_heat }
  end
 end
end
```

method inside user model:

```
  def update_heat
   self.heat -= 10
   self.save
  end
```

then I ran:

```
crontab -r 

whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```

EDIT:
I have taken out the job from the namespace and seems that it did the trick.Thanks for the help

Comment: what's in your crontab (`crontab -e`)?

Comment: try adding `require 'jobs/SubstractSomething` to your `application.rb'

Comment: It doesnt work, it tells : cannot load such file

Comment: Point the require to the correct location (to load the `SubstractSomething.rb` file)

Comment: `runner 'Site::SubstractSomething.execute'` doesn't contain `new()` is that just a typo when copying to S/O ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to `require 'SubstractSomething'` in your `schedule.rb` and make sure that your `$LOAD_PATH` includes the directory it is situated in. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671318/understanding-rubys-load-paths) for some possibilities on how to achieve this.

Comment: I have added it to the load_path and still have the same error. But accesing it from the controller like: Site::SubstractSomething.new().execute , now works.  Why does it fail from crontab command..

Comment: @LogofaT I vaguely remember, that `crontab` shells have a different environment, you should print out your `$LOAD_PATH` before requiring your script. If its directory is in the path it will be found.