# what does the following line do in the following ruby code?

Tags: ruby

what does this line mean?

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path('../../../lib', __FILE__)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Ruby's load paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671318/understanding-rubys-load-paths)

Comment: It means that whoever wrote this doesn't understand `require_relative` and shouldn't be allowed to write Ruby code.

Answer (score 2):

`$LOAD_PATH` is an array. Try running `$LOAD_PATH.class` in irb to prove it to yourself. The unshift method of Array adds something to the beginning of the array. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-unshift

In this case, it adds the absolute path of the ruby file, up three directories, then down into lib.
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path